# I have one table with loan accounts. from that table i want to get current ongoing loan and its respective previous but still ongoing loan account

Tags: sql, oracle

The table has information like open_date, close_date, first_disb_date
when i try to compare prev_loan.date_last_disb < curr_loan.date_acct_open
i will get the result that i want but in case if a customer got two loan at the same date
i will get both of the account numbers when i only need the very last one just before the current loan

```
SELECT ds.cust_id,

        dt.acct_no curr_loan,

        ds.acct_no prev.loan

   FROM acct_dtls dt

  INNER JOIN acct_dtls ds

     ON (dt.cust_id = ds.cust_id)

  WHERE dt.date_last_disb IS NOT NULL

    AND ds.date_last_disb =

        (SELECT MAX(s.date_last_disb)

           FROM acct_dtls s

          WHERE s.cust_id = dt.cust_id

            AND s.date_last_disb < dt.date_last_disb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Updated code to suit your requirements:

WITH RankedAccounts AS (
  SELECT
    ds.cust_id,
    dt.acct_no AS curr_loan,
    ds.acct_no AS prev_loan,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ds.cust_id ORDER BY ds.date_last_disb DESC) AS RowNum
  FROM acct_dtls dt
  INNER JOIN acct_dtls ds
    ON (dt.cust_id = ds.cust_id)
  WHERE dt.date_last_disb IS NOT NULL
    AND ds.date_last_disb < dt.date_last_disb
)

SELECT cust_id, curr_loan, prev_loan
FROM RankedAccounts
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Comment: No. You are still joining all previous row to the last one. They only want to join one row, namely the one preceding the last one. Using `ROW_NUMBER`is a good start, but you should not join, but invoke it one the original rows. Thus you'll have the last two rows per customer numbered 1 and 2 and can work on with these.

Answer (score 0):

Per customer you want one result row containing the ultimate and penultimate loans. One way to achieve this is by using `LAG` to get a row's predecessor and `LEAD` to get a row's successor:

```
SELECT
  cust_id,
  acct_no as current_loan, 
  prev_acct_no as previous_loan
FROM
(
  SELECT
    cust_id,
    acct_no,
    LAG(acct_no) OVER (PARTITON BY cust_id ORDER BY date_last_disb) AS prev_acct_no,
    LEAD(acct_no) OVER (PARTITON BY cust_id ORDER BY date_last_disb) AS next_acct_no
  FROM acct_dtls
  WHERE date_last_disb IS NOT NULL
) with_prev_and_next
WHERE next_acct_no IS NULL
ORDER BY cust_id;
```